# Slide Image 400px from Current Location with CATransition

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a UIImageView that I have aligned right where I want it in my XIB file. When my viewController is called, I would like to have the image move to the right about 400px over the course of 3 seconds. Then I would like the image to fade-out.

I have been playing around with QuartzCore and CATransition and have been able to fade an image out over time with:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
        animation.duration = 0.4;
        [coverImage.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];


        coverImage.hidden = true;
```

However, I would like the image to slide to the right. Anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CATransition` for moving images is quite overkill. I would recommend using UIView animations, then you would simply do

```
// UIImageView *coverImage = ...

// This will move the image to the right and then fade it out.
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
    coverImage.center = CGPointMake(coverImage.center.x + 400, coverImage.center.y);
    coverImage.alpha = 0.0f;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

//there is subtype property which provides transition from right or from left. You have to just set this property as given below

```
 animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
```

Comment: Add this as a comment or put some clarification for a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *coverImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 200, 400)];
coverImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:coverImage];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    coverImage.frame = CGRectInset(coverImage.frame, -400, 0);
    coverImage.alpha = 0.0f;
}];
```